# Gocv! Rgb to grayscale

Tags: opencv, go

I'm having troubles to convert images to grayscale, can you help me at this?
I'm new at Go and in go cv, but I have done a semester at image processing, I'm doing a project in the best path to take some supplies in 7 different spots.

```
package main

import (
    "gocv.io/x/gocv"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    pizzaPath := filepath.Join("Mars.bmp")
    window := gocv.NewWindow("Hello Mars")
    windowB := gocv.NewWindow("Hello Gray Mars")

    MarsImg := gocv.NewMat()
    Marsgray := gocv.NewMat()

    MarsImg = gocv.IMRead(pizzaPath, gocv.IMReadColor)
    Marsgray = gocv.ConvertTo(*Marsgray,0) 

    window.IMShow(MarsImg)
    window.WaitKey(0)

    windowB.IMShow(Marsgray)
    windowB.WaitKey(0)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried ```gocv.IMReadColor to gocv.IMReadGrayScale.``` ?

Comment: I've done that, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but still comes up in search results...so here's the answer that worked for me:

1. Use `gocv.CvtColor(marsImg, &marsGray, gocv.ColorBGRToGray)` rather than `marsImg.ConvertTo(&marsGray, 0)` to convert to grayscale
2. Be sure to pass a pointer to the greyscale Mat (i.e. `&marsGray`) in the parameter list, rather than the value of the Mat (i.e. `*marsGray`)

This example was helpful: https://github.com/milosgajdos/gocv-playground/blob/master/03_Colors_Thresholding/README.md#colorspaces

Here's some minor tweaks to the original code that work for me (with `Mars.png` in the current directory for simplicity):

```golang
import (
    "gocv.io/x/gocv"
)

func main() {
    window := gocv.NewWindow("Hello Mars")
    windowB := gocv.NewWindow("Hello Gray Mars")

    marsImg := gocv.IMRead("./Mars.png", gocv.IMReadColor)
    marsGray := gocv.NewMat()

    gocv.CvtColor(marsImg, &marsGray, gocv.ColorBGRToGray)

    window.IMShow(marsImg)
    windowB.IMShow(marsGray)
    windowB.WaitKey(0)
}
```